# jsTree render multiple trees on same razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, jstree

Im' using jsTree library to render a tree which display a hierarchical relationship of db data calling a controller function via ajax. The problem is that I need two trees on the same view and while the first one is correctly visualized, the second ajax call is deliberately ignored. Below my code

```
<div id="jobstree" />         --> rendered
<div id="costCentersTree" />  --> skip the entire call

<script>
$(function() {

    $('#jobstree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': function(node) {
                    return "/Home/GetNodes/";
                },
                'data': function(node) {
                    return {
                        'id' : node.id,
                        'text': node.text,
                        'children': node.children
                    };
                }
            },
            "multiple": false,
        },
    });

    $('#costCentersTree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': function(node) {
                    return "/Home/GetCostCenterTree/";
                },
                'data': function(node) {
                    return {
                        'id': node.id,
                        'text': node.text,
                        'children': node.children
                    };
                }
            },
            'multiple': false,
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is the controller endpoint being hit? place a console.log in the javasript is that executed? when placing the first call in comments, is the second one rendered? double check your ID', is there an error in the console screen? Check the network tab to see what data is being retrieved

Comment: yeah it is indeed a controller endpoint, the second one is totally skipped and zero errors in console. If you mean 'node.id' they are unique cause they are a concatenated string

Comment: what if you switch the two JS calls?

Comment: it just call the first one so "jobstree" is not rendered whereas "costCentersTree" it is

Comment: maybe this can give some insight: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/568

Comment: It seems useful, I'll look that in deep and let you know if I managed to figure it out